# Concatenated string in python in the loop area

Tags: python

I face a problem of concatenating values in a loop:
I have the following code:

Array:
[(1,2), (1,2), (1,2)]

```
mc1 = mydb.cursor()
mc2 = mydb.cursor()

mc1.execute("SELECT * FROM pdf WHERE id_primarie = 1 LIMIT 10")
myresult = mc1.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  id_pdrimarie = x[1]
  id_pdf = x[0];
  
  sql = "SELECT * FROM proprietari WHERE id_pdf = %s"
  adr = (id_pdf, )
  mc2.execute(sql, adr)
  result = mc2.fetchall()
  
  prop = "";
  for y in result:
    #print(y)
    nume = y[3]
    prenume = y[4]
    #print (nume)
    nume_firma = y[29]
    
    #prop1+=" %s %s + " % (nume, prenume)
    if nume == "":
        prop+= nume
        prop+=" "
        prop+= prenume
        prop+= " + "
        print"-------"
    else:
        prop+= nume_firma
        prop+=" + "
  print(prop)
```

And in the prop variable it should look like this:

1 2 + 1 2 + 1 2

I need to concatenate from position 1 and from 2 and from 3 but between positions to be an + insert

I can't even do that :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre]. This code will not run because many of the variables are not assigned, so we don't know what's in them. Additionally, you'll fail with a SyntaxError on `print"-------"`. Finally, while not an error currently, your indentation is inconsistent. Please use 4 spaces for indentation, as this is the accepted community standard, defined in [PEP 8 -- The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Use the `join()` method

Comment: Edited the question and insert query mysql relevant

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this:**

```py
arr = [(1,2), (1,2), (1,2)]
arr_str = []

for i in arr:
    arr_str.append((f'{i[0]} {i[1]}'))

arr_str = ' + '.join(arr_str)

# or single line

arr_str = ' + '.join(f'{i[0]} {i[1]}' for i in arr)

print(arr_str)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 + 1 2 + 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `join()` method with a generator.

```
result = [(1,2), (1,2), (1,2)]
arr_str = " + ".join(" ".join(map(str, nums)) for nums in result)
print(arr_str)
```